# How to calculate the p-value for Poisson distribution in python?

Tags: python

## Question

Infection rates at a hospital above a 1 infection per 100 person-days at risk are considered high. A hospital had 10 infections over the last 1787 person-days at risk. Give the p-value of the correct one-sided test of whether the hospital is below the standard.

Question link: https://towardsdatascience.com/40-statistics-interview-problems-and-answers-for-data-scientists-6971a02b7eee

## Setup

```
poisson distribution f(x;lam) = e^-lam   lam^k
                                ---------------
                                    k!


k = 10 # infections
lam = (1/1000) * 1787


Using excel .poission, it gives p-value = 0.032372


How to get this value using python?
```

## How to get p-value using python?

Comment: [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html) provides a [poisson](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#statsrefmanual) if it may provide what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I could not find the p-values. They give a lot of RVS but not p-values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the [cdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), in your scenario, the probability that the number of infections will take a value less than or equal 1/100 * 1787.

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
poisson.cdf(10,1787/100)
0.032371526287371055
```